# Software to cap a specific program's network usage speed?

Tags: internet

I am looking for a piece of software in which I can set a max download/upload speed per program. Here's my situation:

I am developing a game that relies heavily on the player's internet speed, and to optimize my networking, I'd like to know whether or not my game will perform well with slow internet speeds (50 KB/s, etc...). What I'd like to be able to do is open up a piece of software, select my game's process (.exe), and set a max download/upload speed for that task specifically so that I can test with various speeds, is there anything like this out there?

Comment: Does it matter which operating system?  If so, please specify!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Windows, I humbly suggest using [NetBalancer](https://seriousbit.com/netbalancer/) for this.  You can limit the download and upload speeds and, I do believe, the demo application would be sufficient to determine if it's worth investing in or not.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of which operating system you are on you should be able to limit your bandwidth for the whole computer, (a more realistic test), by using a browser to access your routers settings.